# removing sources.list and sources.list.d

Tags: ubuntu, warnings, package, ubuntu-16.04

I have deleted sources.list and sources.list.d file with making bakup of them due to theses warning and errors

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian/dists/35x/InRelease: Signature by key 514A2AD631A57A16DD0047EC749D6EEC0353B12C uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
```

the Question Is there any method of restoring them or creating them from scratch because I have configured that I have lost to much things and commands and packages versions